# Disk-to-tape using Networker and Data Domain

Tags: backup, tape, emc

[My previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/267913/disk-to-disk-backup-to-same-storage-array) covered disk-to-disk backup to reduce our backup window, and now I also need to take the disk backup and move it to tape. Is this something I can do with Networker and deduplicated backup?

I know that an ideal solution would be to replicate the Data Domain elsewhere, but we are one site only. Another Data Domain and datacenter space somewhere else is a bit too rich for us. So the new plan is to backup our storage over an iSCSI SAN to a Data Domain 600 using EMC Networker, then have Networker make full backups from Data Domain (not the live data) to tape on a weekly basis. This should give us a fast backup, but allow for offsite disaster recovery.

So can this be done with Networker? If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that EMC kept all of the documentation behind a login wall unless you are a customer, but it turns out that's not true. So I was able to download the manual and check it out myself.

Turns out you can take the Data Domain backup to tape. In Networker lingo, this is a backup clone. This will lose the Data Domain's deduplication, but the clone should be readable by Networker in a disaster recovery situation without the Data Domain hardware.

That's what I see from the manuals, anyway. Still wouldn't mind getting a sanity check from someone who has actually used Networker, but I may have what I need.